# CDH4 Hbase using Pig ERROR 2998 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, noclassdeffounderror, cloudera

I am using CDH4 in a pseudo-distributed mode and I have some trouble working with HBase and Pig together (but both work fine alone).

I am following step by step this nice tutorial:
http://blog.whitepages.com/2011/10/27/hbase-storage-and-pig/

So my Pig-script looks like this

```
register /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.2.jar
register /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.1.2-security.jar
register /usr/lib/hbase/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar

raw_data = LOAD 'input.csv' USING PigStorage( ',' ) AS (
listing_id: chararray,
fname: chararray,
lname: chararray );

STORE raw_data INTO 'hbase://sample_names' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage ('info:fname info:lname');
```

But upon entering following command

```
pig -x local hbase_sample.pig
```

I get following error message

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter
```

Main reason I found online would be the classpaths, so here's a list of the current configuration, maybe you find some nonsense in my configuration:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/lib/hbase
export HBASE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hbase/conf
export PIG_HOME=/usr/lib/pig
export PIG_CONF_DIR=/etc/pig/conf

export PATH="$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/bin:$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$HBASE_HOME/bin"
export PIG_CLASSPATH="$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PIG_HOME/bin"
```

If you need more details, here's the complete pig stack trace:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:478)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:508)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:791)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:780)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:4583)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.store_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:6225)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1335)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:789)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:507)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:382)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1594)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1545)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:545)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:970)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:386)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:189)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:430)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 28 more
================================================================================
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `PIG_CLASSPATH` is wrong, it should look like the following:

```
export PIG_CLASSPATH=”`hbase classpath`:$PIG_CLASSPATH”
```

This will add your missing hbase-related jars to your classpath for Pig.