# Pig - exception on simple load

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I just started learning pig and trying to do something with it, so I enter the pig console and simply type `a = load 'sample_data.csv';` ( I have a file named `sample_data.csv`). I received the following exception:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. name

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: name
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserStringStream.<init>(QueryParserStringStream.java:32)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.tokenize(QueryParserDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1571)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
================================================================================
```

The content of `sample_data.csv` is:

```
1, John, Smith
2, Jane, Doe
3, George, Washington
4, Ben, Franklin
```

I have also set the `$PIG_HOME` variable to the home folder of the pig directory.

I am also aware of the similar question that's been raised before. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402206/cdh4-hbase-using-pig-error-2998-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoo?rq=1)

However, even if I set my `$PIG_CLASSPATH` variable as instructed, and `echo`ed the `$PIG_CLASSPATH` to make sure that it is set correctly, I still get the same error.

Comment: Try checking out http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201206.mbox/%3CCAOkn+GjPCgY1i+-zfNWF9cKz+m8feRj=6Rk1shSS293oqECbMg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Which version of Pig are you on? What environment are you on? This sounds a lot like http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201210.mbox/%3C-1591595176741112468@unknownmsgid%3E

Comment: I saw that post as well. It sounds like I need to add the `$PIG_HOME`/lib into `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. I did that as well even though I noticed that there's nothing in `$PIG_HOME`/lib except `jpython-standalone-2.5.3.jar`. However, still out of luck.

Comment: I am using Red Hat Enterprise Server 64-bit edition with Pig 0.11.1 (the newest version).

Comment: Try this "export PIG_CLASSPATH=/HADOOP_HOME/conf" as well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

After scratching my head for 24 hours. I finally figured it out with the help of my colleage.

It was becuase of `Hive`. For some reason when both `Pig` and `Hive` are set on the same machine, this tends to happen. So all I needed to do is

```
export HIVE_HOME=
```